# Sort HTML Table with Javascript but not sortable by end user

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table, ranking

I am looking for a simple Javascript solution to arrange an HTML table by descending numerical value of a single column, in other words a ranking. Most solutions I have found are more complicated than I need and make the table headers sort the columns when clicked.

I simply want to rank the table in the back end so what the user sees is the table row with the most 'points' at the top and cannot re organize the table themself. I would be manually changing the 'points' value within the html body.

Comment: Why can't you sort the records on the back-end before displaying them?

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately, a question like this is likely to be closed because software and library recommendations are off topic here.  Questions should be focused on a specific issue or problem you are having with a specific technology.  A better question might be "I am having trouble locking a grid using `<SomeJavascriptLibrary>`.  Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: Pick a Wikipedia page with a table, like this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Oklahoma and copy the code (HTML, CSS and Javascript) from it. Those kids made a very good job!

Comment: Usually you'd sort the table in the database query or on the server code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The question was a bit pre-mature, I will ask more specifically when/if I have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use tablesorter.js for this: 
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

The implementation is rather easy:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery("#myTable").tablesorter({headers: {  1: {sorter: false} }}); 
});
```

Read the documentation on how to sort things:

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```